# CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION BSOD Windows 8.1 with Intel HAXM Android Emulator installed

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-8.1, bsod, haxm

I've had frequent "Critical Structure Corruption" BSODs ever since installing Windows 8.1. I even bought a new computer thinking it was just Windows 8.1 being more sensitive to a potential hardware fault.

But the BSODs kept coming in thick and fast while doing pretty much nothing at all, not even running an emulator.

I had a kernel problem panic on my mac with the recent Mavericks and it led me to put two and two together and it seems that simply having Intel HAXM installed on Win8.1 was causing BSODs.

Uninstalling Intel HAXM stops the BSODs.

Ultimately, this question I'm guessing would be resolved when Intel or MS make an update that fixes the BSODs.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is currently a known issue, to track progress see the following over at intel's forums

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475129

Last update: Intel have released a hotfix for windows 8.1

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-windows-hotfix

For now, using GenyMotion for my hardware accelerated emulator needs.

Comment: Lucky I found your post, just started with the x86 based android emulator and suddenly this BSOD showed up. Thanks man!

Comment: Didn't think there was a problem on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: It would be really wonderful if Google could update the version included in the ADT Bundle. I just reinstalled it on my machine the other day and the updated HAXM binary still isn't included.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) rev. 4 from the Android SDK Manager supports Windows 8.1. It supersedes the hotfix described below.

---

From [Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager), install `haxm-windows_r03_hotfix.zip`, which is a Windows-8.1-specific hotfix. If you previously ran the HAXM installer bundled with the Android SDK, uninstall it first.

To aid setup of future development computers, I put the following in the Build Instructions section of my project's readme:

```
Run the Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) installer:
 - On Windows 8.1, from [HAXM](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager), install `haxm-windows_r03_hotfix.zip`, which is a Windows-8.1-specific hotfix.
 - On Windows 8 and earlier, install `adt\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\IntelHaxm.exe`.
```

Comment: Just a note, there is no need to uninstall the HAXM bundled with Android, the new installer takes care of that automatically.

Comment: @0plus1 No, it didn't; at least not for me. Had to uninstall 1.0.6 to install the "hotfix".

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!

> Alexander Weggerle (Intel)  Wed, 11/06/2013 - 02:09
>
> Great news: The hotfix is available for download! Please go to
>       http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/ .
>       There is a hotfix for Microsoft Windows* 8.1 and for OS X 10.9. 
>       Let us know if the hotfix is working for you.

I installed it and HAXM works. Hope that no BSODs any more.

Answer (score 1):

Last update from Intel:

> Alexander Weggerle (Intel)  Mon, 10/28/2013 - 02:39
>
> We have confirmed that we found the root cause of this issue. It's
> related to the GDT. The Intel HaXM team is testing an update to
> support newly released OSes (Microsoft Windows* 8.1 and OS X
> Mavericks*).  This will probably take some days until we fully
> validated it. I will keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was fixed by updating this software component on my 64bit 8.1.

SCSI Pass Through Direct (SPTD) layer (64 bit). Basically SPTD is similar to other access layers used by other programs who provide access to storage devices but it has a lot more features that make this interface unique.

Issues addressed:
- Problem with attach to some physical drives.

http://www.duplexsecure.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the ways and they didn't work. The way I finally fixed the BSODs was saving all of my important files to a disk and resetting my pc to factory mode. I've been working for almost a week now and no blue screens have popped up